# Spring security in angularjs returns 403 forbidden for login

Tags: java, angularjs, spring, spring-security

In a new big applikation I'm involved with, I'm trying to use spring-security.
I've used [this guide](https://spring.io/blog/2015/01/12/the-login-page-angular-js-and-spring-security-part-ii), since it mimic what I'd like to do:

Though I can't seem to login, since the /login is forbidden, and I've done what it says in the guide, but no luck.

**Error request**
[image: error request picture]

**Security config (Java)**

```
@Configuration
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .httpBasic()
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/img/**", "/index.html", "/home.html", "/modules/**/**/**", "/", "/translations.js")
                .permitAll()
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated()
                .and()
                .csrf()
                .csrfTokenRepository(csrfTokenRepository())
                .and()
                .addFilterAfter(csrfHeaderFilter(), CsrfFilter.class);
    }

    private Filter csrfHeaderFilter() {
        return new OncePerRequestFilter() {
            @Override
            protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)
                    throws ServletException, IOException {
                CsrfToken csrf = (CsrfToken) request.getAttribute(CsrfToken.class.getName());
                if (csrf != null) {
                    Cookie cookie = WebUtils.getCookie(request, "XSRF-TOKEN");
                    String token = csrf.getToken();
                    if (cookie == null || token != null && !token.equals(cookie.getValue())) {
                        cookie = new Cookie("XSRF-TOKEN", token);
                        cookie.setPath("/");
                        response.addCookie(cookie);
                    }
                }
                filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
            }
        };
    }

    private CsrfTokenRepository csrfTokenRepository() {
        HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository repository = new HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository();
        repository.setHeaderName("X-XSRF-TOKEN");
        return repository;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think your server looks nearly right (but see the answer below about login.html). Your client is sending a POST to a non-existent endpoint though. Look at the code from the article again and copy the client more closely. N.B. it *has* changed since originally published.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I faced the same scenario when I wanted to return UNAUTHORIZED response in case of log in failure. I handled it by adding a log in failure handler:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.formLogin().failureHandler(new AuthenticationFailureHandler() {
        private final Log logger = LogFactory.getLog();

        @Override
        public void onAuthenticationFailure(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, AuthenticationException exception)
                throws IOException, ServletException {
            logger.debug("Returning UNAUTHORIZED HttpStatus: " + exception.getMessage());
            response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED, "Authentication Failed: " + exception.getMessage());
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: You definitely don't need to do that. Look at the code in the article and in github.

Answer (score 2):

looks like /login is missing in below url matching patterns which will skip authentication for listed urls.

.antMatchers("/img/**", "/index.html", "/home.html", "/modules/**/**/**", "/", "/translations.js")

Comment: He doesn't add the /login into the antMatchers in the guide either. He writes:
GET /login 200 Whitelabel login page (ignored)

Comment: Sorry I just noticed that section of the article was out of date (updated now). @user3247727 is probably correct.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the great project jhipster.

Else you will find an example on the generated project : https://github.com/jhipster/jhipster-sample-app/